# Retrieve Product category 'NAME' by product category ID - WooCommerce?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

Can I retrieve woocommerce product category name by ID?

Not thumbnail, not the URL, not the Sub-categories, just raw Category name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by):

```
$id = 42;
if( $term = get_term_by( 'id', $id, 'product_cat' ) ){
    echo $term->name;
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks.

It wasn't working before, but I changed 'product_category' to 'product_cat' and it worked

Comment: oh sorry, forgot the taxonomy name woocommerce uses.